# Passing Array into Function in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I am currently working on a c++ program that uses the function. When I run the code, I am getting 3 error that

```
error: ‘userInput’ was not declared in this scope
error: ‘displaySum’ was not declared in this scope
error: ‘displayAverage’ was not declared in this scope
```

I'm not sure if the problem is the passing the array into function or I forgot to declare the function itself.

Here is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int numbers[10];
    
    userInput(numbers, 10);
    displaySum(numbers, 10);
    displayAverage(numbers, 10);
    
    return 0;
    
}

void userInput(int input[], int num)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= num; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter #" << i <<": ";
        cin >> input[i];
    }
}

void displaySum(int averageResult[], int num, int sum)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= num; i++)
    {
        sum += averageResult[i];
        cout << "\nSum:" << sum;
        
    }
}

void displayAverage(int averageResult[], int num, int sum, int average)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= num; i++)
    {
        sum += averageResult[i];
        average = sum / i;
        
        cout << "Average:" << average;
        
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to declare your functions before you can call them.  Order matters.

Comment: Unrelated to question: You want to exit your loops already when the index reaches `num`, not afterwards.

Comment: I also recommend watching https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk&t=1384s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
userInput(numbers, 10);
```

When your C++ compiler reaches this line it will have absolutely no idea what this mysterious function called `userInput()` is all about. The C++ program gets compiled in logical order, from beginning to the end, and this function has not been declared yet.

You will need to add a *forward declaration* at the beginning of the file:

```
void userInput(int input[], int num);
```

This *declares* the function. The actual *definition* of the function can remain where it is, after your `main`. This *forward declaration* tells your C++ compiler what this function is all about.

The same thing applies to the other functions in your program.

Additionally, your program has one more fatal bug that you will discover after fixing this compilation error:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= num; i++)
{
    cout << "Enter #" << i <<": ";
    cin >> input[i];
}
```

Your `num` array has 10 values, it is declared as `int numbers[10];`. In C++ array indexes begin with 0, not 1, so this means that the values in your array are `numbers[0]` through `numbers[9]`.

If you work out, on paper and pencil, what the above `for` loop does: you will discover that it iterates with values of `i` ranging from 0 to 10. The loop's condition is `i <= num`, with `num` being 10, so `10 <= 10` is obviously true.

Subsequently this loop will attempt to initialize `numbers[10]` which does not exist, resulting in undefined behavior and a likely crash.

You will need to fix this bug here, and in your other `for` loops, which all have the same bug.